# How to sort an array with this kind of structure like {x1, y1, x2, y2,...}?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of points that being flattened like this:

```
let arrayOne = [0, 0, 1, -1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1];
```

This is an unsorted array of points that have structure `[x1, y1, x2, y2, ...]` where even index elements are `x` and odd index are `y`.

I want to use this function to sort `arrayOne`:

```js
//I putted "arrayTwo" here for comparison with "arrayOne"
let arrayTwo = [[0, 0], [1, -1], [2, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]];

arrayTwo.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[0] === b[0] ? a[1] - b[1] : a[0] - b[0];
});

console.log(arrayTwo);
```

The only problem is that the sort function is only work with `arrayTwo` but not `arrayOne` as I wanted.

How to sort `arrayOne` using that sort function like the way it sorted `arrayTwo` and make it return flattened array like structure of `arrayOne` without creating additional array or object just for grouping xy together ? And if possible provide code that make it work ?

It should do something like:

```
sort(arrayOne, function(a_x, a_y, b_x, b_y) {
    return a_x === b_x ? a_y - b_y : a_x - b_x;
});

console.log(arrayOne); //arrayOne should be [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 2, 0]
```

Note: Because I don't know how to deal with this so I don't know how to implement that `sort` function

Comment: Need to group them first, then flatten resultant

Comment: Did I said that I don't want to group xy together? :( . Is there other ways workaround beside grouping them then flatten then again ?

Comment: I guess this maybe the only way to work with :(

Comment: Unless you want to write a very complex manual sorter then *grouping -> sorting -> flattening* is easiest way and is not difficult to do